# Controlling the throughput of a Process

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

I'm trying to control the throughput of a `Process[F, A]` with a timer `Process` :

```scala
val p: Process[List,Int] = Process.iterateEval(0)(i => List(i + 1))

val timer: Process[Task, Duration] = time.awakeEvery(1 second)(Strategy.DefaultStrategy, Strategy.DefaultTimeoutScheduler)

val p2 = p.zipWith(timer)((v, d) => v)
```

But the compiler says that `p2` is a `Process[Object, Int]`. According to `zipWith()` signature, it should be a `Process[Task, Int]`.

How can I throttle the output of my `Process[F, A]` if `F` is not a `Task`? I tried with `sleepUntil()` but I had similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why `F` won't be anything else than a effect full monad, like an `Task`. If your code does not need any effects, then you may use type processes like Process0 (Process[Nothing,O]).

Your code will just work perfectly ok if you change

```
val p: Process[Task,Int] = Process.iterateEval(0)(i => Task.now(i + 1)))
```

or if `f` passed to iteateEval is pure, just simply

```
val p : Process0[Int] = Process.iterate(0)(i => i + 1)
```

Comment: My `F` is actually not a `Task` but a `Rand` monad (from the breeze library, but could be any kind of other monad). I think I would need to use a monad transformer and I was wondering if there is something ready to use in scalaz-stream to transform a `Process[F1, A]` to a `Process[F2, A]` for any F1 and F2.

Comment: the `F` of course maybe anything, and you perhaps may see we using this flexibility to construct various transducers. However in your case the `F` must be any monad that holds the zipWith signature (F2[x]>:F[x]) where `F` in your case is task.

Comment: There is `F` translation combinator called `translate` that however requires you to write polymorphic F ~> G, however not sure how you want to write Rand ~> Task

Comment: If you just want source of random numbers, the just evaluate Rand command wrapped in task, simple recursion shall do the job (Process has internally trampoline so is safe to do not tail recursive operations).

Comment: I think that the `translate` method will work. In my case, I'm sampling random durations so writing a Rand ~> Task should make sense. Thank you!